# How to create jQuery function for Dynamic Laravel Routes

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

My Laravel application use lots of hyper links in dataTables. And I want to create a jQuery or PHP function which accepts route name, an ID and a display name (for anchor tag). Right now I'm using the following code everywhere.

```
  id = data.location.session_location_id;
  display = data.location.name;
  url = "{{route('session-location.show', '_id_')}}";
  view_url = url.replace('_id_', id);
  link = "<a href='"+ view_url +"'> "+ display + "</a>";
```

I want to create a function that return this link. but the problem is blade doesn't accept jQuery variable i.e in route()function. Same problem with PHP. if I try to write php like this

```
 function show($route, $id, $display)
{

    $url = route($route, $id);

    $link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $display . '</a>';

    return $link;
}
```

it doesn't work either.. Any suggestions?

Comment: and how are you displaying it in the blade? can you tell that?

Comment: Thats the problem. I cant.

Comment: @Exprator I can pass the route name and display name but the ID is dynamic (jQuery). I can't pass that in this PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper function in Laravel.

Refer to the following link or google it you will find tons of examples.

```
https://medium.com/teknomuslim/how-to-create-helper-functions-in-laravel-d769d12218d4
```

Using this you can create a function which accept `$route`, `$id`, `$display` and return `$link`.

In your blade file just pass the params like

```
{{ getLink($route, $id, $display) }}
```

you will get the link.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

**Edit**: in your route file create a route

```
Route::post('/getLink', 'UserController@getLink');
```

In the user controller (you can use any controller which has no access restrictions, so you can make request from any user) create a function:

```
 public function getLink(Request $request) {
     $route = $request->input('route');
     $id = $request->input('id');
     $display = $request->input('display');
     $url = route($route, $id);

     $link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $display . '</a>';

     echo  json_encode(array("success"=>true,"link"=>$link));
 }
```

In any blade file using jQuery, make an AJAX request to the above url.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     id = data.location.session_location_id;
     display = data.location.name;
     url = "{{route('session-location.show', '_id_')}}";

     $.ajax({
           url: "/getLink",
           type: "POST",
           data: {id : id,display: display, url: url},
           success: function(data) {
               var d = $.parseJSON(data);

               if(d.success) {
                    alert(d.link);
               }
           }
    });
 });
```

This is just an overview please check for syntax errors and modify the code as per your need.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm doing. But how can I pass jQuery variable in this function?

Comment: You need to make a function in controller, pass the jQuery variable in that controller using AJAX. Return the link in that function using json_encode. In the blade file read the returned data using $.parseJSON(data) and display the link in your blade file using jQuery.

Comment: Could you give me an example  @Smit Raval. I want to keep the code as short as possible. Because I'm using it everywhere.

Comment: even you can make a common function in common.js and put the ajax code in that function. Pass the params from blade file using jQuey and it will send the ajax request to getLink. By this you just have to include common.js in each file and a couple of lines of code to send route, id, display using jQuery on page load. :)